# Stored procedures get unmapped on data model changes in Entity Framework 4

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework-4

I'm using VS2010, .NET 4.0, and Entity Framework 4 on a new project.  I've been building out the data model iteratively and just started adding some stored procedures.  Every time I "Update Model From Database," the stored procedure mappings disappear from my project and it breaks at runtime.  I assume I'm missing something fairly simple.  Has anyone seen this happen?  Do I have something checked or unchecked that's torching my proc mappings with each update?

Thanks!

Comment: Are your stored procedures using temporary tables? If so, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128747/ef4-the-selected-stored-procedure-returns-no-columns

Comment: unfortunately, no.  They're actually just doing SELECTS, but the logic was complicated enough that i wanted to capture it in the database itself and not in the Entity Framework code

Answer (score 0):

Are your project have setup the permission to see the stored procedures and function import mapping.

There is existing thread which might help you 
[vs-2010-edmx-stored-procedure-missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416083/vs-2010-edmx-stored-procedure-missing)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the procedure from your Data Model and again add it from DataBase.